# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que a una cadena de texto ingresado por input, cada vez que encuentre el carácter de espacio haga un salto de linea?

Tags: python, input

Soy nuevo en Python, me esta contando la cantidad de caracteres y luego repite la frase esa cantidad de veces

```
a8=input("Ingrese un texto ")
b8=("\t")
for n in a8:
    if n==b8:
        print("\n")
    else: print(a8)
```

Comment: `\t` es el caracter de tabulación, no es "espacio".

Comment: Como dice Candid Moe, `\t` representa el caracter de tabulación, no el espacio (que se representa como `" "` en Python). `\t` es el caracter que se crea cuando apretas tab en un editor de texto como el bloc de notas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás imprimiendo la línea `a8` por cada iteración del `for` (que no sea espacio), además debes saber que `print()` por defecto tiene implícito un salto de línea. Para arreglarlo usando tu lógica:

```
a8 = input("Ingrese un texto: ")
b8 = " "
for n in a8:
    if n == b8:
        n = '\n'
    print(n, end='')
```

Otra forma de resolverlo, con `split()`

```
a8 = input("Ingrese un texto: ")
lista = a8.split(' ')
print('\n'.join(lista))
```

Con `replace()`

```
a8 = input("Ingrese un texto: ")
print(a8.replace(" ", "\n"))
```

Con [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re
a8 = input("Ingrese un texto: ")
print(re.sub('\s', '\n', a8))
```